# Error when adding field to Inquiry form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Working with the Voucher transactions inquiry, I've added a custom field to the GeneralJournalEntry table.

When I try to add this field to my inquiry form, it adds correctly (renders as a drop down), and I can input a value or select one from the drop down list -- the issue is if I attempt to put in a wildcard character (*), I'll get a stack trace error:

```
SysDictType object not initialized.


(S)\Classes\SysTableRelation\getDictFieldID - line 7
(S)\Classes\SysTableRelation\findRelation - line 41
(C)\Classes\SysLookup\lookupTableRelation - line 13
(C)\Classes\SysLookup\lookupRange - line 133
(C)\Forms\SysQueryForm\Data Sources\Range\Fields\RangeValue\Methods\lookup - line 36
(C)\Classes\FormStringControl\PerformDBLookup
(C)\Classes\FormStringControl\lookup
(C)\Forms\SysQueryForm\Designs\DesignList\RangeValue\Methods\lookup - line 27
```

There aren't any modifications to these classes, and I can't find anything that would lead me to believe that the wildcard is invalid in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because the method `\SysTableRelation\getDictFieldID` uses the EDT of the field at the line `dictType = new SysDictType (sysDictField.typeId ())` line;

I fixed by adding an EDT to the field.

Comment: Yes, ultimately there was an issue with some work from a different modification, and a missing EDT was the culprit

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you haven't fully compiled/sync'd everything and/or you need to restart the AOS.  You should be able to debug this with the debugger though.

If you look at the code in the top of the stack trace, it's referring to this bit of code:

```
dictType = new SysDictType(sysDictField.typeId());
if(dictType.arraySize() > 1) // <--This is the error...that it's not initialized
```

You can see where I added my comment, that if that is not initialized then it means the above line failed to create a dict type.  `sysDictField` however had no issues returning the `typeId()`.

Put a breakpoint on `\Classes\SysTableRelation\getDictFieldID - line 7` and just see what the issue is. I'm suspecting it's just environment acting up and some compiles/restarts will fix.